# i don't know why this iconbutton i created doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend, flutter-dependencies

```dart
class TodoItem extends StatelessWidget {

  final Todo todo;
  const TodoItem({super.key, required this.todo});

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return  ListTile(
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
      selectedTileColor: Colors.red,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
      ),
      tileColor: Colors.grey,
      leading: **IconButton(
          color: Colors.black,
          iconSize: 18,
          icon: Icon( 
            todo.isDone ? Icons.check_box : Icons.check_box_outline_blank
            ),
          onPressed: () {
              todo.isDone = !todo.isDone;
          },
        ),**
      title:  Text(
        "${todo.body}",
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 25,
          color: Colors.black,
          decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
        ),
      ),
      subtitle: const Text(
        'date',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 15,
        ),
      ),
      trailing: Container(
        height: 30,
        width: 30,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
        child: IconButton(
          color: Colors.white,
          iconSize: 18,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the class but the problem is:

```dart
leading: IconButton(
          color: Colors.black,
          iconSize: 18,
          icon: Icon( 
            todo.isDone ? Icons.check_box : Icons.check_box_outline_blank // here is just giving me the checkbox
            ),
          onPressed: () {
              todo.isDone = !todo.isDone;
          },
        ),
```

Didn't try anything eles ...  i know another way that can work but it's just an icon

Comment: how would flutter know to re-render the widgets when you change the `isDone` value? you need some kind of state management here. e.g. you could use `ChangeNotifier` in your model along with `Consumer` around `IconButton`, or you could use a stateful widget. anyway you should get a grip of how reactive UIs and flutter works

Comment: it is probably working but you're useing stateless widget so value is todo.isDone is Changing but UI is not updating! Use StateFull Widget so you can use SetState() method to update the UI,

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem:
first i have to use a stateful widget and in the onPressed function i need to use the setstate function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setState((){})` after changing the value of `todo.isDone` by making the widget `StatefulWidget` or use can declare value of `isDone` in `Todo` as `ValueNotifier` of type bool and wrap the `ListTIle` in `ValueListenableBuilder` to get the UI re-render and changes get reflected.

Answer (score 0):

To update your view you can use a stateful widget and setState.Here is the code.

```
  class TodoItem extends StatefulWidget {

   final Todo todo;
  const TodoItem({super.key, required this.todo});

   @override
   State<TodoItem> createState() => _TodoItemState();
   }

   class _TodoItemState extends State<TodoItem> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return  ListTile(
  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
  selectedTileColor: Colors.red,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
  ),
  tileColor: Colors.grey,
  leading: IconButton(
      color: Colors.black,
      iconSize: 18,
      icon: Icon( 
        widget.todo.isDone ? Icons.check_box : Icons.check_box_outline_blank
        ),
      onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            widget.todo.isDone = !widget.todo.isDone;
          });
      },
    ),
  title:  Text(
    "${widget.todo.body}",
    style: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 25,
      color: Colors.black,
      decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
    ),
  ),
  subtitle: const Text(
    'date',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 15,
    ),
  ),
  trailing: Container(
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.red,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
    ),
    child: IconButton(
      color: Colors.white,
      iconSize: 18,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}